# Airflow dag import error no such file or directory

Tags: docker, airflow

I'm running airflow on a google VM server using docker and I have a bunch of tasks I want to run.
I have my scripts inside the dag folder and even if I'm using an absolute path to read a csv file (os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(**file**))) I get : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/airflow/dags/bearish_abandonedbaby/updates3.csv'.

What is strange also is that I can't see an airflow folder inside /opt/ on the server but I can see it inside the container, and inside the container the file is there.
Please let me know what am doing wrong.?

Edit :
docker-compose.yaml :

```
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.1.2}
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}"
  depends_on:
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: version
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}

  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

Comment: How do you deploy your Airflow docker there? Docker compose?

Comment: Yes, running docker-compose up

Comment: Can you please provide more details? Your docker-compose file, where you put your dags  etc. etc. ? Without those details it is impossible to help you.

Comment: I edited the post. I put my dags under '/home/ubuntu/airflow/dags'

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not follow the "environment initialization" part in the instructions here:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#initializing-environment

```
mkdir ./dags ./logs ./plugins
echo -e "AIRFLOW_UID=$(id -u)\nAIRFLOW_GID=0" > .env
```

The "dags", "logs", "plugins" folder are mapped from your local directory where you are so you are not supposed to see "/opt/airflow/dags" in the host.

The line above makes sure that airflow is run with your user id and that it has access to those directories.

If you have not followed those instructions you might want to remove those directories as they will likely be created with different user and re-execute the initialization

Comment: I did, it created folders under '/home/ubuntu/airflow' (this is where I ran the commands) and under  '/home/ubuntu', I remarked that dags get synchronized when I put them under '/home/ubuntu/airflow/dags' so this is where I put my actual dag and scripts files

Comment: I stopped and deleted the containers and restarted the whole process and made sure to include these commands, but I still have the error

Comment: I get the same error if I change path to my actual host path : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ubuntu/airflow/dags/bearish_abandonedbaby/symbols.csv'

Comment: Where actually you get this error? You have not explained that? What do you do to get that  error?

Comment: I had the error on dag import. It's fixed now. The problem was that the script run when it gets imported from the dag file